# Database join - results shown in gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have three databases on three different servers that I need to join and show the result in a asp:gridview.  I have the query working now as the result of asp:SqlDataSource using the connection string to one database, but my problem is that I specify the server, database and table for the other two databases.

1. How do modify my query to use a connection string to all of the
   databases (C#, asp example)?
2. Do I do my query in the aspx file or should I do the query in the cs file?
3. How do I attach my result to the gridview if I do the join in the cs file? The data could be different once I leave this page and come back.

My current `<asp:SqlDataSource>` code is this -

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT A.batchname AS IndexBatchNumber, a.clientkey, a.packagetrackingid, a.statusflag, f.Name AS Client, SELECT GroupValue FROM FSDev.dbo.ClientGroup WHERE ClientKey = a.clientkey AND GroupCode = 'TIME ZONE') AS Timezone, (SELECT fc.special_instr FROM SQL2.sysdba.FC_SLX_TEST.FC_PKG_TRKG fc WHERE
fc.fc_Pkg_trkgid = a.PackageTrackingID) AS RushFunding FROM BatchExport a, InvoiceExport b, FSDev.dbo.Clients f WHERE a.batchname = b.batchname AND a.clientkey = f.ClientKey AND a.statusflag = 1 "></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: are the databases on separate servers?  do they have different names across environments?

Comment: Yes they are on different servers, and different names .. development ones have dev, production has prod as part of the names.

Comment: Did you consider creating a view on database side that joins all three tables from different source and returns data from one source?

Comment: These questions are missing a lot of information.  Do all three databases share the same schema for the table in question?

Comment: No the schema is different but they have common index's which is why I can do the joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve this by doing two things. Since the databases are all MSsql, I used the link capabilities to join them together. That way I only have to have a single connection string. In order not to have to change the SQL code when moving to production servers, I had the DBA create stored procedures for all of my queries. This way I only have to change the connection strings.